# NHibernate Criteria against an <ANY> Mapping

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I have a Project model that has a property of type IProjectWorker, this could either be a single User or a Team.  In Castle ActiveRecord it's defined like this:

```
[Any(typeof(int), MetaType = typeof(string), TypeColumn = "WorkerType", IdColumn = "WorkerID", Cascade = CascadeEnum.None)]
[Any.MetaValue("USER", typeof(User))]
[Any.MetaValue("TEAM", typeof(Team))]
public IProjectWorker Worker { get; set; }
```

Now I need to be able to search for projects where the worker's name contains some text.  My initial reaction was something like this:

```
query
   .CreateAlias("Worker", "Worker")
   .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("Worker.WorkerName", SearchText, MatchMode.Anywhere));
```

But this gives me an error-- "any types do not have a unique referenced persister".  This makes sense, it doesn't know how to handle joining to the two different tables for the search.

Can I make two different aliases for each table and do a Restrictions.Or() across them?  I tried it, but couldn't quite get it right.  Or is there some other way to do this using criteria that I'm missing?  Or am I going to have to use HQL instead?

Comment: Have you got an answer?